# login path FOS Userbundle without prefix

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I would like to have the login page on my.vendor.org/ instead of my.vendor.org/login.

My security.yml looks like this

```
form_login:
    provider: fos_userbundle
    csrf_provider: security.csrf.token_manager
    check_path: /login_check
    login_path: /login
    default_target_path:  /home
    use_forward:    false
    failure_path:   null
```

if i change login_path to:

```
 login_path: /
```

I will get an error:

No route found for "GET /"

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by overriding the security.xml file. Note that the route with ID: fos_user_security_login has path "/" instead of "/login"

```
<!-- app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/config/routing/security.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

    <routes xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/routing"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/routing http://symfony.com/schema/routing/routing-1.0.xsd">

        <route id="fos_user_security_login" path="/" methods="GET POST">
            <default key="_controller">FOSUserBundle:Security:login</default>
        </route>

        <route id="fos_user_security_check" path="/login_check" methods="POST">
            <default key="_controller">FOSUserBundle:Security:check</default>
        </route>

        <route id="fos_user_security_logout" path="/logout" methods="GET">
            <default key="_controller">FOSUserBundle:Security:logout</default>
        </route>

    </routes>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have included this as a comment but lack the reputation

This is a very unconventional way to conduct your user logins. Please differentiate where you want to display a login form on the home page and any other pages or whether you want the home page to actually be the login page.

I would prefer the first method but your question is phrased as the second.

To answer your question. Make sure the routing file for the app's home route has not been restricted to methods [POST]. That route is now managed by FOSUserBundle so you will have to check and probably hack it there if there is any issue hence why I would advise you to reconsider your approach.

The first method is very easy, just create a html form with a post parameter to your fos login check url like so

....

```
<form action="{{ path('fos_user_security_check') }}" method="post" class="pure-form" style="display:inline-block; margin: 5px;">
    <input type="text" name="_username" required="required" placeholder="Username or Email" style="width: 150px;"/>
    <input type="password" name="_password" required="required"  placeholder="Password" style="width: 150px;"/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="remember_me" name="_remember_me" value="on" style="display:none;" checked/>
    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token('authenticate') }}" />
    <button type="submit" class="pure-button pure-button-primary">Log In</button>
</form>
```

....

Make sure to add csrf_token as a global twig variable in your config.yml like so

....

```
# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"
    globals:
        fos_csrf_provider: "@security.csrf.token_manager"
```

....

Comment: the reason why there is a login page on the home page is that the web-application is a web-app on the local network only. It doesn't need any other information.